# Compare monthly data while retaining daily granularity

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql, window-functions

I have the below data which contains monthly targets for a set of ids. The targets are for each id, for every month in 2020. The table named `targets`. The `month` column indicates the month of year.

```
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| month | name  | id | target |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 1     | Comp1 | 1  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 2     | Comp1 | 1  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 3     | Comp1 | 1  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 1     | Comp2 | 2  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 2     | Comp2 | 2  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 3     | Comp2 | 2  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 1     | Comp3 | 3  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 2     | Comp3 | 3  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 3     | Comp3 | 3  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 1     | Comp4 | 4  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 2     | Comp4 | 4  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
| 3     | Comp4 | 4  | 6000   |
+-------+-------+----+--------+
```

I then have a second table which contains daily data for a set of ids and is updated daily. In my actual dataset, I've got data from 2019-01-01 up until current day.

```
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| yyyy_mm_dd | name  | id | actual | region |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-01 | Comp1 | 1  | 1000   | LATAM  |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-01 | Comp1 | 1  |   0    |  EU    |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2019-01-02 | Comp1 | 1  | 2000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-03 | Comp1 | 1  | 4000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-01 | Comp2 | 2  | 1000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-02 | Comp2 | 2  | 2000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-03 | Comp2 | 2  | 3000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-01 | Comp3 | 3  | 1000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-02 | Comp3 | 3  | 2000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-03 | Comp3 | 3  | 8000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-01 | Comp4 | 4  | 1000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-01-02 | Comp4 | 4  | 2000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2019-02-03 | Comp4 | 4  | 3000   |  EU    |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
```

Based on the above two tables, I want to create a third table with some additional logic. Ultimately, I want to have a new column introduced called `payment`. This column should always be 0 unless the company has passed their monthly target. If the monthly target is met/passed, the payout should then be `sum actual for that month - monthly target for that month * 1%`.

Here is how the output data might look:

```
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| yyyy_mm_dd | name  | id | actual | payout |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | Comp1 | 1  | 1000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | Comp1 | 1  | 2000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-03 | Comp1 | 1  | 4000   | 10     |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | Comp2 | 2  | 1000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | Comp2 | 2  | 2000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-03 | Comp2 | 2  | 3000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | Comp3 | 3  | 1000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | Comp3 | 3  | 2000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-03 | Comp3 | 3  | 8000   | 50     |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | Comp4 | 4  | 1000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | Comp4 | 4  | 2000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
| 2020-02-03 | Comp4 | 4  | 3000   | 0      |
+------------+-------+----+--------+--------+
```

All names/ids in the above dataset have a monthly `target` of 6000. So there should only be a `payout` when a name/id passes that target during the month. Comp1 and Comp3 both passed the monthly target on the third day of January so they get a payout from that day onwards until the end of the month. This then resets in February as it's a new month with a new target and we'll get new daily data as the month progresses.

---

What I've tried:

```
SELECT
    agg.yyyy_mm_dd,
    agg.name,
    agg.id,
    CASE WHEN agg.actual >= targets.target THEN ((agg.actual-targets.target)/100) * 1 ELSE 0 END AS payout
FROM(
    SELECT
        sum(x.actual) AS actual,
        x.yyyy_mm_dd,
        x.name,
        x.id
    FROM(
        SELECT
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            name,
            id,
            cast(actual as int) as actual
        FROM
            schema.daily_data
        WHERE
            yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-01-01' AND (name = 'Comp1' OR name = 'Comp2')
    ) x
    GROUP BY
        2,3,4
) agg
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
      id,
      month,
      target
    FROM
        schema.targets
) targets ON targets.id = agg.id
GROUP BY
    1,2,3,4
```

However, the above outputs multiple rows per `name`. This is a result of the daily table having the same company multiple times per day (expected). I thought my grouping would have handled that. Also, I don't think it's the most simple solution overall and I'm probably overthinking it / could be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've now got a working solution. The below is giving the output as expected. It could probably be optimized a bit as it isn't the quickest.

```
SELECT
    x.yyyy_mm_dd,
    x.id,
    x.name,
    x.actual,
    x.target,
    x.actual_to_date,
    CASE WHEN x.actual_to_date > x.target THEN ((x.actual_to_date - x.target) /100) * 1 ELSE 0 END AS payout
FROM(
    SELECT
        daily.yyyy_mm_dd,
        daily.id,
        daily.name,
        daily.actual,
        t.target,
        SUM(daily.actual) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(daily.yyyy_mm_dd), daily.id ORDER BY daily.yyyy_mm_dd RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS actual_to_date
    FROM(
        SELECT
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            id,
            name,
            sum(cast(actual as int)) as actual
        FROM
            daily_data_table
        WHERE
            yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-01-01'
        GROUP BY
            1,2,3
    ) daily
    INNER JOIN
        monthly_target_table t
        ON t.id = daily.id AND t.month = month(daily.yyyy_mm_dd)
    WHERE
        daily.name = 'Comp1'
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to compare the cumulative sum of `actua` per company and month to the `target`. You could do this with a join and a window function:

```
select 
    d.yyyy_mm_dd, 
    case when sum(d.actual) over(partition by d.name, t.month order by d.yyyy_mm_dd) > t.target
        then (sum(d.actual) over(partition by d.name, t.month order by d.yyyy_mm_dd) - t.target) / 100.0
        else 0
    end payout
from schema.targets t
inner join schema.daily_data d
    on  month(d.yyyy_mm_dd) = t.month
    and d.name = t.name
where
    d.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-01-01' 
    and d.name in ('Comp1', 'Comp2')
```

Comment: In the daily data, the `yyyy_mm_dd` is stored as a date. The monthly table doesn't have dates, only the `month` which is stored as an int.

Comment: @stackq: I understand. Hive does it differently that other databases. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is some syntax errors and I fixed them, but this one I'm not sure: `Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'yyyy_mm_dd'`

Comment: @stackq: I fixed a few typos too. Are you still getting errors?

Comment: Hi, the same issue persists with your changed code. `Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '1'`

Comment: @stackq: I think that hive doesn’t like the inequality conditions in the `on` clause of the `join`. I changed the query so it uses an equality instead (although this might be less efficient). Is it working now?

Comment: this runs now, but the output isn't as expected. I'm seeing multiple `id`s for a single day in the output. This is a result of `daily_data` sometimes having multiple rows per `name` for a single day. I have edited the sample data to reflect this. Could you modify the solution to reflect this also?

Comment: @stackq: ok so you need to aggregate daily data per day, name and id. I modified the query.

Comment: Looks better now, thanks! If I also select `d.actual` in the top level SELECT, this outputs the daily value of `actual` on each row. Does this mean the case statement is comparing the daily `actual` to the monthly `target`? It should be the sum of `actual` for the month compared to the `target` month respectively.

Comment: @stackq: yes, that's what the query does. The `sum` of `actual` is computed in the subquery, and aliased in the outer query.

Comment: In the subquery the `sum` of `actual` represents the aggregated `actual` at a daily level per `id`. The case statement required is the `sum` of the daily `actual` compared to the monthly `target`. Currently it doesn't do that. As the targets are monthly, we will never have a payout by comparing daily `actuals`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your request for running (partial) sum of actuals is easily solvable by window functions. Unfortunately I don't use Hive, so here is my Postgres working solution

```
with t (month, name, id, target) as (values
  (1 , 'Comp1', 1 , 6000 ),
  (2 , 'Comp1', 1 , 6000 ),
  (3 , 'Comp1', 1 , 6000 ),
  (1 , 'Comp2', 2 , 6000 ),
  (2 , 'Comp2', 2 , 6000 ),
  (3 , 'Comp2', 2 , 6000 ),
  (1 , 'Comp3', 3 , 6000 ),
  (2 , 'Comp3', 3 , 6000 ),
  (3 , 'Comp3', 3 , 6000 ),
  (1 , 'Comp4', 4 , 6000 ),
  (2 , 'Comp4', 4 , 6000 ),
  (3 , 'Comp4', 4 , 6000 )
), d (yyyy_mm_dd, name, id, actual, region) as (values
 ( date '2019-01-01' , 'Comp1' , 1  , 1000 , 'LATAM' ),
 ( date '2019-01-01' , 'Comp1' , 1  ,    0 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-02' , 'Comp1' , 1  , 2000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-03' , 'Comp1' , 1  , 4000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-01' , 'Comp2' , 2  , 1000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-02' , 'Comp2' , 2  , 2000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-03' , 'Comp2' , 2  , 3000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-01' , 'Comp3' , 3  , 1000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-02' , 'Comp3' , 3  , 2000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-03' , 'Comp3' , 3  , 8000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-01' , 'Comp4' , 4  , 1000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-01-02' , 'Comp4' , 4  , 2000 , 'EU' ),
 ( date '2019-02-03' , 'Comp4' , 4  , 3000 , 'EU' )
)
select dr.yyyy_mm_dd, dr.name, dr.id, dr.actual,
       case when dr.running_sum < t.target then 0 else (dr.running_sum - t.target) / 100 end as payment
from t
join (
  select dg.*, sum(actual) over (partition by name order by yyyy_mm_dd) as running_sum
  from (
     select yyyy_mm_dd, name, id, sum(actual) as actual
     from d
     group by yyyy_mm_dd, name, id
  ) dg
) dr on dr.name = t.name
     and month(dr.yyyy_mm_dd) = t.month -- edited to hive equivalent of postgres' extract(month from dr.yyyy_mm_dd) = t.month
```

The month extraction from date may be done different way but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi. In hive the month extraction is like this: `and month(dr.yyyy_mm_dd) = t.month`. However, I get multiple companies per day in the output. I believe you should group by company in the `dr` subquery. Could you edit the solution?

Comment: Month comparison edited. I thought you wanted "multiple companies per day" according to your sample output in question. The absence of `group by` in `dr` is intentional since to compute running sum you need to preserve each row for each company. The `partition by` clause splits window into groups but does not aggregate them.

Comment: I do indeed want multiple companies on the same day but not of the same `id`. For example, 2020-01-01 will have 3 companies but the same company doesn't occur more than once. In your solution, the output gives the same company multiple times for a single day. In my real data `d` does have multiple `ids` per day for some companies but not all. I want to aggregate this and keep it daily as per the sample output. Hope I cleared that up

Comment: I have edited the original question and updated the sample daily data to reflect multiple companies per day. Hopefully the problem makes sense now.

Comment: I am closer to understand what you mean, however, your changed example does not show any case of two rows equal in date and name and differing in id. Instead, there is new column region with unclear value ordering. Proper value ordering is important for computation of running sum (what if target for `2019-01-01 | Comp1` was 1000 and there were two 1000 values with different region?). Also it would be very convenient for anyone willing to help to get sample data as CTE instead of ascii-art tables.

Comment: I added one row on `2019-01-01` for `Comp1` in the daily data. Now there is two rows on `2019-01-01` for `id` 1. I want the output to have one row. So the `target` should be compared to the aggregated `actual` for each `id` for the same month. I will try to upload some data.

Comment: I've now uploaded the data. [Daily data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/7a186416feb7f8a00d97e4f4e5cfa0ef/daily_data.csv) and [Monthly data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/76f8f256371d1e00c417a0675f93b1e3/monthly_data.csv).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to group data before running sum calculation (not sure if `sum(amount)` is what you want, though). I edited answer. I didn't try your csvs since it's inconvenient for me to convert it to CTE (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/653539 ) and there is another unexplained column.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a windowing `SUM` function to create a running total, then use that in a `CASE` statement to get your column values.

```
SELECT d.yyyy_mm_dd
    ,d.name
    ,d.id
    ,d.actual
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 
      SUM(d.actual) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.yyyy_mm_dd ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) <= t.target
            THEN 0
        ELSE 
      (
        SUM(d.actual) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.yyyy_mm_dd ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - t.target
            ) * 0.01
        END AS payout
FROM dailies AS d
JOIN targets AS t 
    ON d.month = MONTH(d.yyyy_mm_dd)
    AND d.id = d.id;
```

I'm not 100% sure on the Hive syntax, but this is pretty close. Specifically, the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` might not be sufficient. You may need a `FOLLOWING` clause in there to get the totals right.

Comment: Hi, this runs but has a similar issue to other answers on this question. The output gives multiple `id`s on the same day. This is because the daily data can have several of the same `ids` on the same day. I have updated the example data to reflect that.